# How to set HTTPS authenticate header in Jython using Java classes

Tags: java, https, jython

I have the following code which works as is.
What I need to set the HTTPS `authentication` in the header.
To keep the question clean, just accept the fact that the python `requests` module can’t be used because of what the vendor did to wrap the Jython runtime.
The Java Classes are at Java 8.

```
  def getAllSafes (self, authenticationBaseURL, sessionToken):
      wwJO = Json.createObjectBuilder().build()
      offset = 0
      limit = 10
      sort = "asc" # ascending
      includeAccounts = "true"
      extendedDetails = "true"
      
      get_allSafes_url = "https://" + authenticationBaseURL + "/PasswordVault/api/Safes?" + "includeAccounts=" + includeAccounts + "&offset=" + str(offset) + "&limit=" + str(limit) + "&sort=" + sort + "&extendedDetails=" + extendedDetails
      wwJO = Json.createObjectBuilder().build()

      vault_url = URL(get_allSafes_url)
      isr = InputStreamReader(vault_url.openStream())
      JsonReader = Json.createReader(isr)

      print JsonReader.readObject()
      JsonReader.close()
      return "_Determined at run time_"
```

Comment: Do you need to set an authorization header?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912074/https-get-using-jython

Comment: Yes the authorization header is needed.  I can't use urllib2 because the cacert file parameter did not get included until after version 2.7.0.  I am stuck on 2.7.0 with no way to update because the way the vendor imbedded jython in their product.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet of code to set the Authorization header (you'll need to supply the authorizationvalue):

```
    vault_url = URL(get_allSafes_url)
    connection = vault_url.openConnection()
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationvalue)
    isr = InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())
```

Comment: Not working.  I get the following.  Results in the following output…
wwMap.size():14
wwHeader:None
wwHeader:X-Content-Type-Options
wwHeader:Pragma
wwHeader:Date
wwHeader:X-UA-Compatible
wwHeader:Strict-Transport-Security
wwHeader:Access-Control-Expose-Headers
wwHeader:Cache-Control
wwHeader:Set-Cookie
wwHeader:X-FRAME-Options
wwHeader:Expires
wwHeader:X-XSS-Protection
wwHeader:Content-Length
wwHeader:Content-Type

Comment: My bad. The "Authentication" header can not be returned, see.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726697/httpsurlconnection-getheaderfields-not-returning-set-cookie